# Find a grammar for the following language

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

Find a grammar for the following language:

1. a*b | a
2. (a*b | b*a)*

I think I have the answer for 1 (S -> aS | b) but I'm pretty confused on the second one.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your 'answer' for #1 has no way of terminating with just a, so I think you might want to rework that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language; **(a*b | b*a)***

```
S -> SA | epsilon
```

A here represents **(a*b | b*a)**

```
A -> B
A -> C
```

B represents **(a*b)**

```
B -> [Insert rule here]
```

C represents **(b*a)**

```
C -> [Insert rule here]
```

Answer (score 2):

Think of the whole expression `(a*b | b*a)*` as a nonterminal, and then consider each element (i.e, `a*b` is one, and `b*a` is another) inside as separate nonterminals.

Hint:

```
S -> ε | ST
T -> [rule for a*b] | [rule for b*a]
```

`T` is what's inside the bracket.